# htpasswd / htaccess reoccurs asking for login

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a htaccess setup like so.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile "/home/alltest/public_html/.htpasswd"

<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

for some reason for every file linked to the webpage it's requesting the htpasswd details again and i can't work out why it's not saving that i have authorization this is on a Cpanel server if that made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthUserFile /home/alltest/public_html/.htpasswd
require valid-user`

This keeps the password in the browser cache until you exit the browser. I fit's possible, I suggest keeping the .htpasswd file out of the public directory.

If you're using cPanel, there could be something in the config files of the web server...